# Can an Nginx zone (limit_conn_zone or limit_req_zone) be applied independently to multiple locations or do they conflict?

Tags: nginx

Suppose I have two services, `foo` and `bar`, that run on the same server with Nginx as a reverse proxy to the two services. I expect the traffic of `foo` to have a lot more traffic with more frequent requests than `bar` and would like to configure connection limits and rate limiting to reflect this.d

Can you explain how the two configurations would have different behaviors?
Keep in mind the limits make the memory size trivial... I am more concerned about whether connections to foo impact the limits on bar and vice versa (eg: if the same ip has 5 connections to foo and 1 connection to bar, while the connection to bar be denied?)

```
http {
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=foobar_ip:1m;
    limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=foobar_server:1m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=foobar_ip_req_limit:1m rate=10r/s;
    server {
        location /foo/api {
            limit_conn foobar_ip 20;
            limit_conn foobar_server 2000;
            limit_req foobar_ip_req_limit burst=5 nodelay;
            ...
        }
        location /bar/api {
            limit_conn foobar_ip 5;
            limit_conn foobar_server 200;
            limit_req foobar_ip_req_limit burst=5 nodelay;
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

vs...

```
http {
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=foo_ip:1m;
    limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=foo_server:1m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=foo_ip_req_limit:1m rate=10r/s;
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=bar_ip:1m;
    limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=bar_server:1m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=bar_ip_req_limit:1m rate=10r/s;
    server {
        location /foo/api {
            limit_conn foo_ip 20;
            limit_conn foo_server 2000;
            limit_req foo_ip_req_limit burst=5 nodelay;
            ...
        }
        location /bar/api {
            limit_conn bar_ip 5;
            limit_conn bar_server 200;
            limit_req bar_ip_req_limit burst=5 nodelay;
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second configuration meets your requirements.

An incoming HTTP request first match the location, and add up the stats(per server_name, per remote_addr) by limit_zone_name in `access phase` and then enter into `content phase`. So if you put the same limit_zone in two different location, as the limit_zone name is the same, Nginx can not differentiate which API (location) you want limit, the consequence is that two locations' stats are merged into one for checking limit.